# Two of the Same Netbeans Projects on One Server

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

We only have one java server to work on (not counting local) for our dev and test environments. We want to be able to run a dev and a test version simultaneously however, so to solve that I've created two different projects, one for dev and the other for test. Otherwise, even if I change the project properties or rename the war file, the glassfish server recognizes it as the same project we already deployed and undeploys the previous version. Is there a way around this? I know the best thing to do is to have a separate java server, but that isn't possible right now.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish are you using?

Comment: 4.1.1 I believe @skomisa